# Не могу понять как парсить дальше?

Tags: python, json, парсер, requests

Я уже задавал вопрос [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1256212/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5-body-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82?noredirect=1#comment2207313_1256212) и мне дали на него хороший ответ, но я не могу понять как это работает. Благодаря этому коду :

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://api.csgowin.ru/crash/get-history', headers=headers)
data = json.loads(r.content)
```

Я получаю данные с этой [страницы](https://csgowin.ru/crash/history), но еще мне нужно получать данные с каждой истории отдельно для более точного анализа, а как это сделать я не понимаю. Так же я не понимаю откуда взялась эта ссылка `'https://api.csgowin.ru/crash/get-history'`
из кода выше. Я пересмотрел большое кол-во видео по парсингу, читал статьи и документацию, но так и не понял, как работает мой код и как мне получать информацию из каждой истории раундов (пример [раунда](https://csgowin.ru/crash/history/539126))

Comment: `data['data']['rounds']` - это будет список раундов. Дальше делайте с ними что вам нужно. Ссылку скорее всего получили через инструменты разработчика в браузере. Вообще, если что-то не понятно по ответу, можно дописать уточняющие комментарии прямо под ним.

Comment: "откуда взялась эта ссылка": ее можно найти в инструментах разработчика вашего браузера в закладке Network; "тут мне дали на него хороший ответ"... неплохо бы отметить хороший ответ галочкой как принятый ;)

Comment: @insolor вы меня не так поняли, я пытаюсь достать подробные данные из самого раунда (пример [https://csgowin.ru/crash/history/539126]), а из 'data['data']['rounds']' я уже достал все что хотел

Comment: @Jack_oS ой, я не знал что так можно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так же, как в предыдущем твете: найдите, откуда на страницу приходят данные:

```
import json
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36'}

game_id = 539126
r = requests.get(f'https://api.csgowin.ru/crash/get-game/{game_id}', headers=headers)
data = json.loads(r.content)
```

где `game_id` - номер раунда.
Теперь в `data`:

```
>>> data
{
    'success': 1, 
    'data': 
        {
            'game': {'id': 539126, 'crashed_at': 1.02, 'total_bank': 6.75, 'total_items': 11, 'total_users': 11, 'start_at': 1616065927165, 'delay': 0, 'state': 3, 'hash': '41b5369380a98914b3c624867f6ca81074a383861eea15df7086eae71e5ac599', 'salt': '83386f70df70840076f662ddf06de480'}, 

            'bets': [
                {'id': 6282679, 'user': {'id': 239568, 'steamid_64': '76561198029887956', 'nickname': 'Koneko Toujou', 'photo': 'ff/ff73622646b347591c95aa11ecaec77e755e18f2_medium.jpg', 'level': 4, 'custom_avatar': '', 'custom_background': '', 'nickname_color': ''}, 'items': [37474], 'items_total': 1.44, 'items_count': 1, 'cashout_ratio': 1.25, 'win_item': 0, 'status': 2}, 

                ...

                {'id': 6282684, 'user': {'id': 47239, 'steamid_64': '76561199095160349', 'nickname': 'pohuioleg csgowin.ru', 'photo': 'ab/ab15144e6fb80a8545eb1ab83c7d0117ab2583ca_full.jpg', 'level': 3, 'custom_avatar': '', 'custom_background': '', 'nickname_color': ''}, 'items': [22286], 'items_total': 0.25, 'items_count': 1, 'cashout_ratio': 0, 'win_item': 0, 'status': 2}
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: гений просто. Я пытался найти этот api, но не нашел. Теперь буду лучше искать. Спасибо тебе большое!

Comment: @qitsune, теперь вы можете говорить "спасибо", проголосовав за ответ! ;)